# Drupal: can its functions be customized?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I've tried searching the Internet for this but I have not found an exact answer. I've seen that Drupal can use modules and its admin page can be customized, but does its functions can be customized as well?

This is what I want to happen:
after writing an article/content, it would be saved first as a draft and be sent to certain people for deliberation. The people would then have to vote if it is okay. If the article/content gets 70% or more approval, it would be posted immediately to the website.

Can I do this with Drupal? If not, do you have any suggestions on other CMS's where I can do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you had a look through these moderation modules? http://groups.drupal.org/node/71618

Comment: @rdjs Oh, so there's a page for that in Drupal. I've found one that suits the need of my client in the link that you provided. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you probably don't need a custom module to achieve the desired result, you certainly could write your own custom module if you wished to.

This documentation should get you started: http://drupal.org/developing/modules

And this is a great set of examples that provide a starting off point for custom module creation: http://drupal.org/project/examples

Like I said though, you're likely better off using contributed modules that have been vetted by the community. See if the **workflow** module does what you want - search "drupal workflow." You may also need the **fivestar** module to provide a thumbs up for approval - search "drupal rating."